# Enviar contenido de un array JSON a inputs de un formulario html

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estoy trayendo un array de datos con JSON, el cual muestro en diferentes celdas de una tabla en HTML, tal como se muestra abajo:

```
  contenido.innerHTML = ''
                                        contenido.innerHTML =  `
                                          <tr>
                                                <td id="mat" style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.matricula}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.nombre}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.nivel}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.grado}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.grupo}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><img src="${data.foto}"  height="100px" width="100px"/></td>
                                          </tr>`

      contenido1.innerHTML =  `
                                          <tr>
                                                <td id="nom" style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.nombre1}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><img src="${data.foto1}"  height="100px" width="100px"/></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.nombre2}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><img src="${data.foto2}"  height="100px" width="100px"/></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><b>${data.nombre3}</b></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #6FF2AB; color: BLACK;"><img src="${data.foto3}"  height="100px" width="100px"/></td>
                                          </tr>`
```

Aunado a esto, también me pinta unos botones, con los cuales mando llamar una ventana modal donde está el formulario con los input:

```
     cabecera3.innerHTML =  `
                                        <tr style="text-align: center; background-color: green; color: white;">
                                          <th scope="col"><button class="btn btn-danger addret" type="button" value="${data.matricula}"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ret">Retira Tutor 1</button></th>
                                          <th scope="col"></th>
                                          <th scope="col"><button class="btn btn-danger addret" type="button" value="${data.matricula}"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ret">Retira Tutor 2</button></th>
                                          <th scope="col"></th>
                                          <th scope="col"><button class="btn btn-danger addret" type="button" value="${data.matricula}"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#ret">Retira Tutor 3</button></th>
                                          <th scope="col"></th>
                                        </tr>`
```

Ventana modal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código JS para que el botón pintado con la tabla me muestre modal e imprimir datos del array en los input:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.addret', function(){
    var id=$(this).val();
    var first=$('#nom'+id).text();
    var mat=$('mat'+id).text();

    $('#ret').modal('show');
    $('#enombre').val(first);
    $('#ematricula').val(mat);  
});
});
```

Mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo puedo enviar estos datos (o para ser más especifico, enviar o imprimir, por ejemplo, este `${data.nombre1}`) en un input del formulario HTML de la ventana modal?

Comment: Valla el formulario con los input los tengo en una ventana modal, la cual mando llamar con un botón que me pinta junto con la tabla

Comment: Listo @Marcos ya coloque mas código, espero darme a entender

Comment: A ver si entendí. ¿Quisieras que, por ejemplo, al tocar el `button` _"Retira Tutor 3"_ obtener `data.nombre3` e imprimirlo (_imagino_) en el `input` `#tutor`?

Comment: exacto! @Marcos estoy intentando que `${data.nombre3}` me lo muestre en el input del formulario de la ventana modal

Comment: No veo donde has creado los elementos `#matricula[ID]` ni `#nombre[ID]`, etc.. Se me ocurre que la solución que podrias aplicar sería identica, crear `#tutor[ID]`. En el caso que quisieras que no sea visible, podrías usar un `<input type="hidden"`.

Comment: Así es @Marcos estoy intentado hacer eso, solo que no logro colocar los datos como este `${data.nombre3}`  para que se coloquen en los inputs

Comment: Es que no tendrías que hacerlo así. Tendrias que hacer los mismo que estas haciendo en la última imagen de tu pregunta. Es decir, buscar el elemento con ID, obtener el valor y asignarlo al otro elemento.

Comment: @Marcos, es lo que estoy intentando, modifique nuevamente mi pregunta, en la primera imagen se observa que le puse un id al td junto con el valor de data.nombre, y en el js de abajo pienso que seria algo así, no se que mas hacer

Comment: Coloca tu código y no imágenes es mejor para ayudarte